# How can i add the filename/directory of several images in a list/array with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I use PyQt5 and QtDesigner to create a GUI where I can select different photos from a folder. I want the names of the photos to be stored in a list.

For example:

```
[0]: Image_Nike_AirMax_Size/9.0
[1]: Image_Adidas_Continental_Size/8.5, and so on.
```

Then I want to select the information of each photo, such as "Size", and save it separately in a variable.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class Fenster(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Fenster, self).__init__()
        loadUi('Projekt.ui', self)
        #self.b1.clicked.connect(self.gedrueckt)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.button)

    def button(self):
        self.open_dialog_box()

    def open_dialog_box(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, 'Select Multi File', 'default', 'All Files (*)'))

        for name in filename:
            idx = name.find("/")
            print(name[idx+1:])


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = Fenster()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In my code you see an approximation to the goal, but it does not quite work out.

Comment: What is it that "does not quite work out"? Be more descriptive in the problem you encounter, "it doesn't work" is completely unhelpful. For instance, there's an extra closing parenthesis in the QFileDialog line, which would prevent your code to run at all. Also, QFileDialog static functions like that always return a tuple, with the first being the selected file(s) and the second the selected filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below stores files into one list, stores the size of each file into another list, and finally combines the two.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

    def open_dialog_box(self):
        """Open files and populate lists."""
        full_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "Select Multi File", os.getcwd())

        # Store files in list
        self.file_list = []
        [self.file_list.append(path) for path in full_path]

        [print(f) for f in self.file_list]

        # Store size of each file in KB
        self.file_size = []
        for f in self.file_list:
            self.file_size.append(Path(f).stat().st_size)

        [print(f) for f in self.file_size]

        # Combine lists
        self.complete = zip(self.file_list, self.file_size)

        [print(c) for c in self.complete]
```